# python telegram bot password

Tags: python-3.x, passwords, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

To get information from the telegram bot, you need to enter a password. If the password is incorrect, how to write a code to make it not provide information, please help.

```
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text('Добро пожаловать')
    while True:
        Password = update.message.reply_text('введите пароль',update.message.text)
        if Password == "9900":
            update.message.reply_html('Imzo Factory', reply_markup=buttons)
            break
        else:
            update.message.reply_html('введите пароль')
```

Comment: Just remove the `else` statement? Unless I am not understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Hello, when you start the bot, it should say hello and then ask for a password. If the password is incorrect, it should ask again.